# Determine the completeness of $C^2[0,1]$ with respect to a non-standart norm

Tags: functional-analysis, complete-spaces

Is $C^2[0,1]$ complete with respect to the norm $$\left\lVert{f}\right\rVert_A=\max_{x\in[0,1]}\left\lvert{f''(x)}\right\rvert+(\left\lvert{f(0)}\right\rvert^2+\left\lvert{f(1)}\right\rvert^2)^\frac{1}{2}?$$
It is evident, that $$\left\lVert{f}\right\rVert_A\le\sqrt{2}\left\lVert{f}\right\rVert_B,$$where $$\left\lVert{f}\right\rVert_B=\max_{x\in[0,1]}\left\lvert{f(x)}\right\rvert+\max_{x\in[0,1]}\left\lvert{f'(x)}\right\rvert+\max_{x\in[0,1]}\left\lvert{f''(x)}\right\rvert$$is standart norm in $C^2[0,1]$ and with respect to this norm space is complete. But is it enough to prove that $C^2[0,1]$ is complete with respect to $\left\lVert{.}\right\rVert_A$?

Comment: Completeness means that every Cauchy sequence converges. If your estimate allows you to show this, then it is enough. But you should demonstrate that. (So no, from my perspective there is a bit more to do).

Comment: The standard procedure is: assume you have a Cauchy sequnce $f_n$ in that space. 1) find a function $f$ which deserves to be called the limit of that sequence. 2) show  $f$ is a member of the space you are looking at 3) show that $|f-f_n|\rightarrow 0$ in the norm you are looking at.

Comment: It is almost as evident that the converse inequality holds (use the fundamental theorem of calculus twice). Once you have shown this, completeness is trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two norms $\|\cdot\|_A$ and $\|\cdot \|_B$ in a space $X$, such that $\|x\|_A\leq C\|x\|_B$ for all $x\in X$ , and the space $(X,\|\cdot\|_B)$ is complete, then it is not necessary that $(X,\|\cdot\|_A)$ is complete. One example is given by $$X=C[0,1],\quad \|f\|_B=\|f\|_{\infty},\quad\|f\|_A=\|f\|_2.$$ In your case, you can actually show that the two norms $\|\cdot \|_A$ and $\|\cdot\|_B$ are equivalent, and this will imply that $(C^2[0,1],\|\cdot\|_A)$ is complete. To do this, let $f\in C^2[0,1]$. Then there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $$f'(c)=f(1)-f(0).$$ Therefore, for all $x\in [c,1]$, $$\begin{align*}
|f'(x)|&\leq|f'(x)-f'(c)|+|f'(c)|\\
&\leq \int_c^x|f''(t)|\,dt+|f'(c)|\\
&\leq\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f''(x)|+|f(1)|+|f(0)|\\
&\leq \max_{x\in[0,1]}|f''(x)|+2(|f(1)|^2+|f(0)|^2)^{1/2}\\
&\leq 2\|f\|_A,
\end{align*}$$
and similarly, for $x\in[0,c]$, you obtain the same inequality. So, $$\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|\leq 2\|f\|_A.$$ You also obtain a similar inequality for the maximum of $|f|$, which shows that $$\|f\|_B\leq c\|f\|_A$$ for all $f\in C^2[0,1]$. Therefore, the two norms $\|\cdot \|_A$ and $\|\cdot\|_B$ are equivalent.